# Unwrap all images from HTML string in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I unwrap all the images from an HTML string without using jQuery?

```
var htmlString = `
            <p> random text </p>
            <a href="src1"><img src="src1"/></a>
            <a href="src2"><img src="src2"/></a> 
            <a href="src3"><img src="src3"/></a>
            <p> random text </p>
           `;

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = htmlString;

var elements = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
let i = 0;
while (i < images.length) {
   //unwrap all images from parent in pure javascript 
   images[i] ....
}

console.log(div.innerHTML);
```

Expected output:

```
 <p> random text </p>
 <img src="src1"/>
 <img src="src2"/>
 <img src="src3"/>
 <p> random text </p>
```

Comment: I didn't get it. You want to remove the immediate parent tag of all images?

Comment: @JayGhosh yupp exactly

Comment: don't add them in the first place - problem solved

Comment: @JaromandaX wow man that's so smart, I receive the innerHTML from http response I have to filter the response before displaying it

Comment: and yeah downvote me everyone

Comment: What @JaromandaX said. Or, you could dump all of these inside a hidden div and traverse the div accordingly

Comment: I didn't downvote - see your code or your text doesn't explain what you've just said, so, lose the attitude

Comment: @JaromandaX what part of my question you didn't understand? because I can explain..

Comment: I understand the context now that you mentioned it so eloquently in your comment - why would I assume the html comes externally if your code shows it hard coded? Chillax dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a little code I just whipped up

```
[].forEach.call(div.getElementsByTagName("img"), function(img) {
    var a = img.parentElement;
    a.parentElement.insertBefore(img, a);
    a.parentElement.removeChild(a); // can be a.remove() - not sure of cross browser compatibility (shakes fist at IE)
});
```

Comment: it worked with `a.parentElement.removeChild(a);` Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the fix, @AngelPolitis

Answer (score 0):

Sure you just get all the links and within you move the images to root and then remove the links.

```
var parent= document.getElementById('parent');
var linkImages = parent.getElementByTagName('a');

for(linkImage in linkImages){
    while (linkImages[linkImage].childNodes.length > 0) {
        parent.appendChild(linkImages[linkImage].childNodes[0]);
    }
    parent.removeChild(linkImages[linkImage]);
}
```

Something like that. Modify it you serve your purpose.

Comment: But this will check all the links even if they don't contain images

Comment: jezus modify it. i cant think for all your problems. Add some checks

Answer (score 0):

```
function unwrapImages(htmlString){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = htmlString;

    var images = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var i = 0;
    while (i < images.length) {
       var imgParent = images[i].parentElement;
       var img = images[i];
       div.insertBefore(img, imgParent);
       div.removeChild(imgParent);
       i++; 
    }
      return div.innerHTML;
}
```

**This function should unwrap all the images from their immediate parent**